# Do both players need the Lara Croft GoL DLC to play online?

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

If I buy the Guardian of Light DLC, can I invite my friends to join my game without them having bought it, or do they need to purchase it as well?

I was more interested when I thought they were just puzzle maps as they're some of the best co-op bits in the game, but I doubt it would be worth us both buying the packs just for one puzzle map in each pack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both players need to have purchased the DLC to play on the DLC Maps im afraid.

Comment: OK, thanks, I was expecting that but it's still a bit disappointing!